# Can you give me Grhya Sutra 1.22.0, Grhya-Sutra 3.4.4, Grhya, Sutra 2.22.9?

Tags: translation-request, grihya-sutra, source

Professor Kashi Nath Upadhyaya in his "Early Buddhism and Bhagavadgita" page 16-19 says

> Evidences for the existence of the MB after the 1st century A.D. are too numerous and too well known to be recounted here. We may, therefore, begin with the testimony of the works of Asvaghosa, a Mahayana Buddhist of the 1st century A.D. In his ‘Buddhacarita’ as well as ‘Saundaiananda’ he evidently makes use of the episodes of the MB. Again in his *Bajra Suci’, some verses of the ‘Sraddha Mahatmya’ portion of the Harivamsa as well of other portions of the MB are quoted. This indicates that by his time the MB with its appendix, Harivamsha must have been well known. Still earlier references are to be found in the ‘Grhya-Sutra’ of Asvalayana as well as in the Dharma-Sutra and Grhya-Sutra of Baudhayana. Asvalayana makes clear mention of the Bharata as well as the in his Grhya-Sutra 3.4.4. In Baudhayana’s Dharma Sutra 2.2.26 a verse occurs which is found in the MB Adi.78.10. His Grhya Sutra (1.22.8 ) clearly mentions the name of the ‘Visnu-sahasra-nama’ which is a portion of the MB and further in Sutra 2.22.9, an important verse of the Gita 9.26 is clearly quoted. The date assigned to Baudhayana by Dr. Buhler is not later than 400 B.C. By this time the MB seems to have been popular along with Gita, the verses of which are quoted by Baudhayana in high reverence.From the clear mention of the two names, the Bharata and the Mahabharata in the Grhya Sutra of Asvalayana, it is reasonable to infer that the MB was developed from the Bharata, perhaps, not long before Asvalayana, for after a considerable lapse of time, the name Bharata was almost forgotten. As the Gita is not considered as a later addition of the MB , it is reasonable to believe that it might have been composed sometime between the 5th and the 4th century B.G. We shall, however, further examine this question and see whether this date is confirmed on other independent grounds

Where can I find these 3 verses from  Grhya Sutra :

> Baudhayana Grhya Sutra 1.22.0
> Asvalayana Grhya-Sutra 3.4.4
> Baudhayana Grhya Sutra 2.22.9

And you give me English translation of these verses.

Comment: Who voted to close it. And why did that person voted to close it and voted on "Needs details or clarity". What kind of a clarity anyone is expecting. I have give the verse number and the scripture name. And told the language.

Comment: 'What kind of a clarity anyone is expecting.' - Gṛhyasūtras are of several types (https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe29/index.htm) - which one in particular are you looking for?

Comment: @sv I have edited it. I think now you can understand which one I want

Comment: Better than before but you still need to put the grhya sutra name before each verse - both in title and the last line. The question is still a bit confusing.

Comment: @sv I think there is no need of it because I got the answer

Comment: Question is not yours alone, it's a community site so the question needs to be clear even to a new user. The question can be closed as unclear even after receiving the answer.

Comment: @sv done, I have edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translations of requested verses are as below.

> Covering it (the square and lotus referred to in previous verses) with
> pure blades of Kusha grass, he must chant the Vishnu Sahasranama or
> Shiva Sahasranama. (Baudhayana Grhya Sutra 1.22.8)
>
> In case the country is not appropriate, one is without money, then he
> can normally do puja in his mind or offer this is because Bhagavan
> says- “those who give me leaf, flower, fruit or water with devotion I
> eat that which has been offered by my pure minded devotee”
> .(Baudhayana Grhya Sutra 2.22.9)
>
> Sumantu, Gaimini, Vaisampâyana, Paila, the Sûtras, the Bhâshyas, the
> Bhârata, the Mahâbhârata, the teachers of law, Gânanti, Bâhavi,
> Gârgya, Gautama, Sâkalya, Bâbhravya, Mândavya, Mândûkeya, Gârgî
> Vâkaknavî, Vadavâ Prâtîtheyî, Sulabhâ Maitreyî, Kahola Kaushîtaka,
> Mahâkaushîtaka, Paiṅgya, Mahâpaiṅgya, Suyagña Sâṅkhâyana, Aitareya,
> Mahaitareya, the Sâkala (text), the Bâshkala (text), Sugâtavaktra,
> Audavâhi, Mahaudavâhi, Saugâmi, Saunaka, Âsvalâyana—and whatsoever
> other teachers there are, may they all satiate themselves.'
> (Asvalayana Gryha Sutra 3.4.4)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: can you give the sanskrit original text

Comment: http://www.hinduonline.co/vedicreserve/kalpa/grihya/bodhayana_grihya_sutram.pdf 
@DarkKnight

Comment: can you add text in the answer. Because I can't read sanskrit

Comment: You mean sanskrit verses? It aint allowing me to copy @DarkKnight

Comment: then you can screen shots them

Comment: Better to add links to the translations or at least mention the source/translator.